# How do i build Angular2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack

I am new to Angular2. For writing code, I am manually creating the folder structure for my application. This seems like a very clumsy to start a new project.

Is there any better way, similar to how the yeoman generator etc. work?

I recently heard about [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) for creating a project in Angular2, would that be a good option, or are there better generators I should be looking at?

Please share the links if anyone knows the best practice to do it.

Comment: angular-cli is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for `angular-cli@webpack`, it is based on latest `angular2-rc5`. You dont need to look on other generator or packages.

Comment: Thanks pd farhad i will look at it.